# Column Selection not available in ag-grid framework

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have to implement the following scenario in angular using ag-grid. Here i need to do select all for both the columns individually[image: Here i need to do select all for both the columns individually].

But Ag-grid provides row selection only on Select all in the below image. If i click the check box next to Update button,it results in following image which is selecting all the rows.[image]

Is there a way we can enable individual column selection in ag-grid. We need to map Boolean values to these fields.

Comment: Provide your code or build stackbliz please.

Comment: You should split logic from `rowSelection` and create own `headerComponent` for each column to handle certain header checkboxes with data-cell dependency.
Also, it would be required to create `cellRenderer` for cell's to handle header clicks and needed things.